# NetBeans или Eclipse что из них?

Tags: ide, eclipse, c++, netbeans

Что лучше устанавливать для новичка NetBeans или Eclipse?

Какая среда более простая и понятная. (Нужен для изучения С++)

Почему NetBeans?
Почему Eclipse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ни тот, ни другой. Обе среды - хорошие (по-своему) для профессиональной разработки приложений. Для целей же изучения языка они малопригодны. Также я категорически против использования и VisualStudio и любой другой тяжелой профессиональной среды для изучения языка.

С моей точки зрения, для изучения *языка* лучше использовать не полноценную среду разработки с "проектами", "автогенерацией кода", "средствами визуальной разработки", а простой редактор (разумеется с подсветкой синтаксиса) и кнопочками "собрать" и "запустить", и начинать изучение с разработки консольных программ.

Если у Вас какая-либо версия ОС `Linux`, то я бы посоветовал использовать `Gedit` (если среда `Gnome` или `XFCE`) или `Kate` (если среда `KDE`), и запускать компиляцию из командной строки: `g++ -o outfile infile.cxx` - так Вы глубже поймете, что происходит.

Если же работа в консоли совсем пугает, то и под `Linux` и под всеми версиями `Windows` я очень рекомендую `Code::Blocks`. Это свободное программное обеспечение, кросс-платформенное. В большинстве дистрибутивов `Linux` есть в репозитариях. А на сайте http://codeblocks.org/ можно найти сборку под `Windows`, в которую включен и свободный компилятор `GCC`. Если хотите, вот прямая ссылка: http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/10.05/Windows/codeblocks-10.05mingw-setup.exe

Собственно, то же самое я советую и своим студентам :-)

Успехов!

P.S. Сам использую `KDevelop` ;)

Comment: Линукс хочу поставить на неделе,по практикую все что вы посоветовали.

Comment: KDevelop в последние пару лет стал вообще хорош. Настолько, что начал приближаться к приличным IDE.

Comment: Ммм интересно...

Comment: Согласен на 100%

Answer (score 2):

для изучения,лучше всего использовать....vim!
попробую объяснить: так как человек,решивший изучать что-то,собирается ПОЗНАВАТЬ язык,то ему нужны не свистелки и ...мигалки,а лишь код,чистый код,набираемый ручками,а не дополняемый кем-то,различные АйДи - хороши для тех,от кого требуется не знания ,а скорость,а для новичка - понимание кода...
когда ручками пишешь и компилириуешь с флагами,то начинаешь понимать что ты пишешь и зачем,и самое главное - набиваешь руку и мозг,путем набора основных операторов и выражений.Понятное дело что блокнот:""наше всьо!",но ты плюнь на это,возьми Vim,начнешь сразу изучать  работу с клавиатурой,начнешь думать и выражать свои мысли через клаву,без неё никак...осилишь Vim,значит осилишь и язык!
только мозг,пальцы и клавиатура!Рюшечки и и свистелки прийдут потом,когда облом будет набирать "регулярки" без автодополнения и когда от тебя будут требовать и сроки исполнения,а не знания постфиксного или префиксного инкремента.

Comment: Для этого, как ни странно, надо изучить `vim` (ну и регекспы, раз уж на то пошло) - а это отнимает много сил. Поэтому, если идти к минимализму, надо посоветовать `nano` - он *очень* простой и на первый месяц-два его точно хватит.

Comment: Но и толку от него никакого.. он же ничего толком не умеет. Тогда можно использовать любой блокнот с подсветкой: будет куда удобнее и проще.

Comment: Для того, чтобы ездить на машине не нужно знать устройство двигателя. А при необходимости со временем это знание придёт.

Мне кажется, в таком случае лучше скачать Notepad++ и использовать компилятор из командной строки. По крайней мере человек ну будет себе забивать голову vim-овской идеологией, вместо того, чтобы свободно учиться программированию.

Comment: Я так делаю на C# .Пишу в notepad++ и в командной строке остальное дело.

Answer (score 2):

По сути вопроса согласен с первым ответом. Но!
Я самоучка по java. И продолжаю обучение. На некотором этапе стоит постепенно подключать idе. Т.к., к примеру, компилить и исполнять код намного быстрее через ide. Пока не выучил сборку ant'ом и maven'ом, собираю ручками, прописывая зависимости. Но в дальнейшем опять же это заменит ide. Т.к. он сокращает время, которое можно потратить на написание кода или кофе.

Я использую eclipse. Она оказалась порядком проще NetBeans своим интерфейсом. Пробовал обе ide. Начал с Net Beans...месяц крутил её, показалась слишком громоздкой что ль. До конца так и не понял. А почитал про eclipse, посмотрел настройки....всякие сборщики мусора и т.п. Подкрутил конфигурационный файл, и получилось ide, которая порядком быстрее работает чем net beans...

А на самом деле, особой разницы не обнаржил на первых порах обучения. Я остановлю свой выбор на eclipse. Для моих задач его достаточно.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы посоветовал начинать с нормальной IDE а не с блокнота, и уж тем более не с vim. Я начинал изучение с Visual Studio, и в каком-то смысле она мне очень помогла, потому как я не застрял в самом начале с не очевидными для новичка ошибками, и не бился с vim'ом и gcc. А ошибок в начале будет очень, очень много, и нормальная IDE поможет избежать кучи проблем, в некоторых местах выкинет полезные варнинги, в некоторых по человечески отформатирует код. Автокомплит тоже незаменимая вещь, очень многое я узнавал методом тыка, и уже после, подробно из книг и МСДН. А человеческий дебагер чего стоит, можно конечно и в vime дебажить, но для этого надо его сначала еще и настроить!

Все это то же самое, что советовать начинающему программисту, начинать с асмы, что бы лучше понять как устроен мир, и постичь дзен. Все это круто, но набравшись определенного опыта программист к этому и сам придет.

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте оба и попробуйте и тот и другой. Вы быстро поймёте что вам больше по душе. Что бы там ни говорили, но они по функционалу почти аналогичны. А если и есть какие-то существенные моменты, то для обучения они не играют роли.

Comment: Скачал с официального сайта архив 80 мб не работает не знаете почему?
Думаю скачать оба через российские порталы(там чаще рабочие).

Comment: Как это не работает? Такого не может быть. Это через российские порталы качать опасно и ненадёжно ;)

Comment: Пишет что чего то не хватает,долго не парился скачал оба поискав с Гуглом)

Answer (score 1):

Ни NetBeans, ни Eclipse.

Рекомендую Qt Creator, потому что:

- работает под Винду и под Линукс;
- абсолютно бесплатен;
- поддерживается компанией Nokia;
- поддерживает все типы необходимых проектов под винду (VC) и под линукс (Make, CMake...);
- по-умолчанию поддерживает все основные системы контроля версий;
- легковесная и очень быстрая IDE (написана на C++, а не на Java, как Eclipse или NetBeans);
- "рефакторинг" кода: умное переименование функций, переменных и констант сразу во всех исходниках проекта;
- прочие "феньки" Visual Studio + дополнительные вкусные возможности.

+ если дело дойдёт до разработки визуальных компонентов или приложний - то Qt также свободно и одинаково работает как под Линукс, так и под Винду; Qt Creator для этого предоставляет мощнейший инструмент визуального проектирования;

Пусть вас не смущает наличие Qt в названии этой IDE. В своей работе на Qt не разрабатываю вообще, но использую только его.

Comment: Если бы всё было так красиво как вы пишете..

Answer (score 0):

незнаю что там говорят про VisualStudio, вполне удобная для новичка. Никто не заставляет пользоваться всеми удобствами, я вот до сих пор многие вещи даже не использую, для меня главное хорошо видеть структуру кода,например зажал контрол и мышкой на интересующий метод - перешел к определению или описанию метода, так что если комп позволяет по мощности ставь студию и не парься. Плагинов тоже кстати куча всяких есть.

Answer (score 0):

Я соглашусь с мнением всех коллег, так как каждый из них по своему прав.
Но они забывают некоторые просты вещи...
Для новичка в первое время будет важно:
 1. Сколько времени он потратит настраивая ИДЕ
 2. Чтобы интерфейс был интуитивно понятен(выделялась кнопочка для сборки и запуска программы, желательно окно в котором будет выполнятся сама программа)
 3. Подсветка синтаксиса, да это ЗЛО, но очень удобное, так же как и автодописывание кода(знания все же придут со временем).
 4. Минимум излишнего функционала.

Согласно этому из всего тут предложено остается только **Code::Blocks**, проста настолько что с ней даже ребенок справится, поставил и приступил к работе, сам начинал изучать с нее С, потом переключился на С++.

П.С. А тем кто рекомендует блокноты могу сказать только одно... вы для изучения языка выкиньте из своего постоянного использования все STD и тогда вы может быть действительно чему то научитесь, кроме как открывать блокнот и нажимать на клавиши.

(Из всего здесь предложенного сам лично только NetBeans не смотрел)

Answer (score 0):

Для изучения, начинающему: Source Insight OR SlickEdit.
Почему? SI имеет необходимый минимум, позволяя эффективно грести в чужом коде, благодаря очень качественному фолдингу и диаграммам. SE позволяет эффективно бороздить чужое пространство, как и SI, но в отличие от, имеет IDE-ориентацию: язык slickC итд.